# EasyPermissions on Android doesn't grant permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am using **EasyPermissions** library to grant some permissions in my app. This is the scenario:

This is logcat initializing my app and pressing the button.

```
D/HomeActivity: He pulsado ringtoneMenuOpen
D/HomeActivity: onPermissionsDenied
D/HomeActivity: Hemos llegado aquí con permisos denegados y 'No volver a mostrar'
```

Then appear a Dialog (**AppSettingsDialog**) explaining the permission is necessary with Cancel and Accept buttons. I press Accept and *Settings APP screen opens*. I click on Permissions Item and **it's enabled**... I return to the app and Logcat show me **onPermissionGranted** debug note. I make a runtime click in the button again (to enter inside the ringtone setting logic because I have the permission granted) but I go again inside the **onPermissionsDenied** mehod..

```
onPermissionsGranted He pulsado ringtoneMenuOpen
onPermissionsDenied Hemos llegado aquí con permisos denegados y 'No volver a mostrar'
```

This is my class structure (for the info)

```
public class Home implements EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks{

...
private String[] permission_sounds = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
private int RC_permissionSounds = 500;
private Activity act;

..onCreate{
    act = this;
}

//I assign this onClickListener to ringtoneButton
private View.OnClickListener ringtoneMenuOpen(){
        Log.d(TAG, "ringtoneMenuOpen accedemos, tenemos que entrar ahora en solicitar permisos e intentar ");
        soundButtonMode = SoundButtonMode.RIGNTONE;
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "He pulsado ringtoneMenuOpen"); //Line 1 Logcat
                if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(act, permission_sounds)) {
                    new SetSoundAsRingtone(act).execute();
                } else {
                    EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(act, act.getString(R.string.permission_rationale), RC_permissionSounds, permission_sounds);
                }
            }
        };
    }
...
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, act);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, @NonNull List<String> perms) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPermissionsGranted");
        buttonRingtone.performClick();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, @NonNull List<String> perms) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPermissionsDenied");//Line 2 Logcat

        if (EasyPermissions.somePermissionPermanentlyDenied(this, perms)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Hemos llegado aquí con permisos denegados y 'No volver a mostrar'"); //Line 3 Logcat
            new AppSettingsDialog.Builder(this).build().show();
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: Try my library. ;) https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions